# What is the equivalent of getfsstat() on Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Question says it all. I want C function call that returns the list the mounted filesystems along with associated information such as filesystem type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `getmntent` and other `*mntent` functions family.  See [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent) For further reference.

Code example taken from [here](http://www.codase.com/search/call?name=getmntent) and slightly modified.  `/etc/mtab` is a file that contains a list of mounted filesystems.

```
mounts = setmntent("/etc/mtab", "r");
while ( (ent = getmntent(mounts)) != NULL ){
    if (strcmp(ent->mnt_type, "iso9660") == 0)
       /* copy mount point to output */
       strcpy(retval[cd_count - 1], ent->mnt_dir);
    } /* if */
} /* while */
endmntent(mounts);
```

Unfortunately, these functions are not in POSIX.  But they're manpaged and implemented in glibc, so I think they're a better alternative than parsing `/proc`.

Comment: That gives you the info in entries in the `/etc/fstab` file, not the actual mounted filesystems in the kernel (as the FreeBSD's `getfsstat()`)  FreeBSD has it, but linux seems not to have it implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse `/proc/filesystems`.